# why gelocation giving my current location wrong with navigator current location method?

Tags: javascript, navigation, geolocation, location

I am using nabigator.currentLocation but its is giving me coordinates of 400km away location
why so?

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {


    this.currentLocation(position.coords)
             },()=>{},{
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
 });
```

How i could improve this??

Comment: yes i have laptop with gps option

Comment: i am using it on my laptop and mobile both devices giving same results. it doen't seems issue with device.. have you checked your location with this code?

Comment: no that is just my customer function where i am calculating distance nothing else .. those position coordinated are not coorect on my side..actually latitude is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Foundation's docs on using the geolocation API ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API ) say :

> Note: By default, getCurrentPosition() tries to answer as fast as
> possible with a low accuracy result. It is useful if you need a quick
> answer regardless of the accuracy. Devices with a GPS, for example,
> can take a minute or more to get a GPS fix, so less accurate data (IP
> location or wifi) may be returned to getCurrentPosition().

You're giving it 5 seconds, so you're quite possibly geting an i.p. location.

The I.P. location will be your point of presence on the internet, and that depends on how the network (quite a lot of it outside of your control) is put together.

For example, most businesses will have a few points where the internal traffic emerges to the internet - I'm always in a data centre in the Waikato when I use the work VPN.  On the other hand, many ISPs uses ISP-NAT which means you appear to be in *their* data centre to the rest of the web.

To get a better result, you might need to allow more time.  First I'd give it a full couple of minutes in the timeout and see what you get.  Then maybe think about whether you could make two calls, start with the rough (inaccurate) answer and refine it if you get a better answer from GPS later.